# Multiple UITableViews as sub views

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I'm working on a little app to get the grips with Objective-C and the UIKit. My application shall simply display the menus for every weekday that are served at the individual canteens at my university.

---

I have a view containing a `UIToolbar` which itself contains a `UISegmentedControl` to switch between the days. The remaining screen space shall be used for the Table View displaying the dishes served by one canteen at a certain weekday. Now, how do I do this?

I have a `Canteen` that has 5 `Menus` (one for every day) and each of these `Menus` contains an arbitrary number of `Dishes`. The business logic is actually working totally fine by now.

How do I connect my views to my business logic. In my opinion, there are three possible ways and I have no idea which one I should choose:

1. My `CanteenController` - which owns the `UIToolbar` mentioned above - does everything. It implements the protocols necessary to manage a `UITableView` and it owns the `UITableView` that displays the dishes.
2. I have a `MenuController` that uses the `CanteenController`'s `UITableView` - so the `UITableView` is shared among the 5 `MenuControllers`.
3. I have 5 `MenuControllers` that have there very own `UITableViews` and every time I switch between days I replace the current `UITableView` of my `CanteenController` with the right one.

Is there such thing as a correct solution for this problem? I think, all of these solutions should work, but maybe I should prefer one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these solutions will work, and in most cases none of them will cause performance or memory issues.  One advantage to option 3 is that you could easily fade between them upon selection with

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{ /*show new top view by setting alpha from 0 to 1 and bring it to the front*/ }];
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - would be my pick, and reload the data of the table when a new toolbar item is selected.  this allows for less memory to used, which is numero uno stipulation when looking at Apple documentation...Don't use anymore memory than you have to."

2 - doesn't make sense to me

3 - i think would be better handled by a TabBarController that automatically does the view switching for you between each view controller.**